# Grep file when $1 with format "hh:mm:ss" is between a range

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, grep

What I wanted to do, is find out all the entry in my file when the first element in each line, with "hh:mm:ss" format, is between two hours

File format:

```
14:40:00 user1 load xxxx xxxx xxxxx
14:40:02 user2 change xxx xxx xxxxx
15:03:04 user1 change xxx xxx xxxxx
so on...
```

I would like to get al the entry between 14:40:00 and 15:00:00.

I was thinkig to do it with the following command, but I dont know how can follow with the fiter.

```
cat app.log | grep change | awk '{print $1 if .....}'
```

After that I would like to print whole line. Could somebody tell me how can I do conditional filter in command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '"14:40:00" <= $1 && $1 <= "15:00:00"' app.log
```

If you want to pass in the start and end times dynamically:

```
start=14:40:00 
end=15:00:00
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end 'start <= $1 && $1 <= end' app.log
```

If, as you show, you also only want "change" events:

```
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end 'start <= $1 && $1 <= end && /change/' app.log
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end 'start <= $1 && $1 <= end && $3 == "change"' app.log
```

Comment: Good! Didn't know `awk` allows string comparison like this.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a way:

```
$ awk -F: '($1==14 && $2>=40) || ($1==15 && $2==0)' file
14:40:00 user1 load xxxx xxxx xxxxx
14:40:02 user2 change xxx xxx xxxxx
```

I also see you are grepping `change`. You can do it all together:

```
$ awk -F"[: ]" '/change/ && (($1==14 && $2>=40) || ($1==15 && $2==0))' app.log
14:40:02 user2 change xxx xxx xxxxx
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"[: ]"` sets space or `:` as field delimiters. Is not entirely necessary as you could just use `-F:`, but it allows you to "play" with the rest of the fields if you want to.
- `'($1==14 && $2>=40) || ($1==15 && $2==0)'` are the possible conditions to match: `hour 14 + minute >=40` or `hour 15 + minute == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

With perl it would be:

```
perl -n -e '/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \S+ (\S+) / && $2 eq "change" && $1 ge "14:40:00" && $1 le "15:00:00" && print $_' < app.log
```

Or slightly more readable:

```
perl -n -e '/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \S+ (\S+) / ' \
    -e '&& $2 eq "change" ' \
    -e '&& $1 ge "14:40:00" ' \
    -e '&& $1 le "15:00:00" ' \
    -e '&& print $_' < app.log
```